# События от мыши для перекрытых объектов.

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Есть 2 PictureBox. Мне нужно на нижнем ( сером ) получать сообщение от мыши, например о щелчке. Если я щелкаю просто на сером, все хорошо, но если я щелкаю на той части серого которая скрыта под полосатым, то ничего не происходит!

Вопрос, как мне получать сообщения "сквозь" другой PictureBox?

Спасибо за внимание.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C событиями не разобрался, но поступил следующим образом:
Передаю при событии мыши на отпускание объекта его координаты ( btnThis.Location ) в функцию( GetNumPanelMayMove ) и если по данным координатам есть нижний серый квадрат, то устанавливаем новую позицию этого серого квадрата:

```
  int numPanel = panelControl.GetNumPanelMayMove( btnThis.Location ); 
if ( numPanel != -1 ) {

    if ( btnThis.GetColor() == panelControl.GetColorPanelByNum( numPanel ) ){
        SetTargertPosition( btnThis );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверно только [таким](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) путем. Соответственно, надо смотреть функцию [SetWindowsHookEx](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Hook/fn_setwindowshookex.htm). Ну или рисовать все ручками в рамках пользовательского контрола.

Comment: Возможно я не правильно выразился, мне нужно реализовать вот это http://hashcode.ru/questions/272850/ для этого тоже нужны хуки?